# Plot skewness, holding all else constant in R

Tags: r, distribution

I'm trying to see how a pricing model would do under 3 different distributions: left skewed, right skewed and normal distribution.

As a part of this, I need the distributions to sum to the same total amount. The only thing we vary is skewness.

I found this incredibly hard to do, despite this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254084/plot-normal-left-and-right-skewed-distribution-in-r). Is there any functions or package that may assist me?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by having the same area under the curve? Same area within a certain range? Because otherwise the area under the curve for any probability distribution is just 1, isn't it?

Comment: @Marius Ah, I'm thinking in terms of a histogram rather than PDF. Clarified.

Comment: Maybe the `fGarch` package function `rsnorm()` and the `xi` parameter might be useful, as in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28811114/89482